# Get position of disk if moving in reverse direction (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have 3 towers [A, B, C] which I will label in numbers as [1,2,3].

I want to find the position a disk will be in if it moves `n` times in the reverse direction. So if it starts at B or 2 position and moves back 7 times, it will be in A or 1 position.

Is there a general formula I can use to compute this for any given `starting position` and any number of moves `n`? To move forward, I just use

```
(start_pos + n) % 3.
```

However, I am not sure about the reverse direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a modulus operation between a negative and a positive is a positive. I.e., you can use the same general formula, just subtract the number of steps instead of adding them:

```py
(start_pos - n) % 3
```

Or, alternatively, define the number of steps moved backwards as a negative number of steps.